# Fastest way to generate 11,000,000 unique ids

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

I am trying to create php script that generates 11,000,000 million unique ids in sequential order. However, I am trying to do it very quickly within 20 min it should generate these 11 million unique ids. Also, once it reaches 12,000,000 it should wrap around and start back at zero.

Here is what I have so far. This script would would only return one id at a time. I just added a loop to see how long it would take to generate the ids.

```
while(true){

    try {

        $this->getAdapter()->query('INSERT INTO generate_ids (assigned_id) SELECT (MAX(assigned_id)+1) FROM generate_ids');
        $id = $this->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();


        $sql = 'SELECT assigned_id FROM generate_ids WHERE id = $id';  
        $query = $this->getAdapter()->query($sql);
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
            //Live system would return id here
        $assigned_id = $result[0]['assigned_id'];


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    if($count == 11000000){
        die();
    }

    $count++;
}
```

}

Comment: A good first step would be not doing this one row at a time.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `AUTO_INCREMENT`? And why do you have to select the ID you just generated? Are you not trusting the database created the record?

Comment: Yea, like @siride said, doing 1 row at a time will cause 11,000,000 queries to be called, which will be extremely slow... if each request took 200ms, it would take 6,111 hours to run this script I believe.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. Is it important that the generated id values be stored in a table? I don't understand the comment about `//Live system would return id here`, return the id to what process, and how? Do you need to populate a table with 11,000,000 rows? Given you specified a wrap when it reaches 12,000,000, we are to assume that the ids also need to be contiguous (not just unique) and that the range of ids should be 1,000,001 thru 12,000,000 (or 1,000,000 thru 11,999,999)?

Comment: @Joshua Smock: if each SQL execution takes an average of 200ms, that would be on the order of 1,222 hours. (Each time through the loop is two SQL executions (an INSERT and a SELECT): 22,000,000 execs * 200ms = 1,222 hours.

Comment: Oh, oops! I was off by a factor of 10. It would have taken 611 hours, not 6,111. Thanks for pointing that out @spencer7593! And thanks for pointing out there were 2 queries, I missed that - I was assuming it was just an insert query.

Comment: dear @Alex, you should make a small edit, do you mean 11,000,000 million or just 11,000,000 ? (you should remove the million I think, or write 11 million)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE sequence (
     sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_id`)
)
```

Then issue these three queries one after the other:

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES ();
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS sequence;
```

The third query is *guaranteed* to return a unique sequence number. This guarantee holds even if you have dozens of different client programs connected to your database. That's the beauty of AUTO_INCREMENT.

Instead of just generating eleven million of these sequence numbers up front, you can use these SQL queries to get a unique sequence number whenever you need it.

If you must wrap around at sequence number 12 million you can use these queries instead.

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES ();
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() MOD 12000000 AS sequence;
```

The trick here is to use an auto-increment sequence number for uniqueness, but to also delete the rows in the table so it doesn't gobble up lots of space.

Note that you can also use the sequence number of LAST_INSERT_ID() for other purposes, like so for example.

```
INSERT INTO sequence () VALUES ();
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO user (userid, username, phone) 
          VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID() MOD 12000000, 'Joe', '800-555-1212');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() MOD 12000000 AS sequence;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert all your ids at once (for some reason) the fastest approach would be to do it in pure SQL

```sql
insert into generate_ids (assigned_id)
select N
from
(
select a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + d.N * 1000 + e.N * 10000 + f.N * 100000 + g.N * 1000000 + h.N * 10000000 + 1 as N
from (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) e
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) f
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) g
    ,(select 0 as N union all select 1) h
order by N
) q
 where N <= 11000000
```

It takes less than a minute to complete on my laptop.