# Using Json format to decrease JOINs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have many tables in my database, an example is the table fs_user, the following is an extract of the table columns (dealing with privacy settings):

**4 Columns** from the table fs_user:

```
show_email_to
show_address_to
show_gender_to
show_interested_in_to
```

Like many social networks, I need not only to specify which data is private and which is public, but also which data is available to a chosen users, and which one is not.

As I have about 30 data like the 4 data above, I think it will be bad to create one table for every data, and make a many to many relation with the table fs_user.

This is why, I got the idea of saving this data in a Json form for every column (whose type=TEXT), example

```
show_email_to => {1:'ALL',2:'BUT',3:'3'}
```

This data means, show email to all users, except the user whose id=3.

Another example:

```
show_email_to => {1:'NONE',2:'BUT',3:'3',4:'80',5:'10'}
```

This means, no user will see the email except the users id=3,id=80 and id=10.

Of course, the MySql query will select this data, and PHP/Js will extract the data I need from Json.

Another point, is that sometimes .. a user wants to show data only to his friends except 3 friends.

This will do :

```
show_email_to => {1:'FRIENDS',2:'BUT',3:'3'}
```

This means that the email will be shown to all his friends, except user with id=3.

**My question is :** How much will be this system performant, flexible (for other uses) compared to the 'many to many' solution (which requires to have many data in many tables)??

Note: I know already that saving many elements in one column is a bad practice, But here: I think this is a json element and can be considered as a **one Object**

Comment: This makes querying for specific values very difficult.

Comment: And if you're going to do something like this, it should be structured like `{"allow": "ALL", "exclude": [3, 4, 80, 10]}`

Comment: This is why I'm already planning to use Memcache in parallel with this, plus the fact that php performs great with json.

Comment: @Barmar, Yeah: I didn't integrate the solution yet...and your alternative is far Better

Comment: Memcache doesn't make it any easier. How would you write a query for "members who allow email to be shown to all"?

Comment: Or better: list all users who don't allow email to be sent to username XXX.

Comment: If you store all this data in a sane relational way, you can easily build the json. But if you store the json and need to do relational activity, you're in for trouble. Say next year an account is hacked an you have to remove an id from everyone's lists. You'd have to write a custom script and iterate over the whole DB...

Comment: Instead of separate relation tables for each permission, you could have a single `permissions` table. It would have a column that defines the action, with contents like `show_email` and `show_gender`.

Comment: I got it, the first solution can deal with different cases ... like `{"allow":"FRIENDS","exclude":[2,3,4]}`

Comment: Your format also makes checking referential integrity difficult. With ordinary relations, you can use foreign key constraints.

Comment: Yeah, I know these limitations... that's why I try to find a better solution with a decreased number of joins (I hate joins), as the system itself is far more complicated that this one table. ( I have also tables of pages, groups, clubs, friendships) and for everyone there are diffirent permissions.

Comment: A many to many relationship, done wisely, is immensely superior to what you are contemplating.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm still modelizing, I'm trying to figure out the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. What you propose is, with respect, a very bad idea indeed if you're using any flavor of SQL. You are proposing to denormalize your tables in a way that will defeat every attempt to speed up searching or querying in the future.

What should you do instead?  You could take a look at using an XML-centric dbms like MarkLogic. It's capable of creating indexes that accelerate various Xpath-style queries, so you would be able to search on relationships.  If you do that, I hope you have a big budget.

Or, you could use normalized permission tables.

```
   item_to_show  (item id)
   order (an integer specifying rule ordering,  needed for this)
   recipient (user id)
   isdenied  (0 means recipient is allowed, 1 means she is denied)
```

In this table, the primary key is a compound key constructed of the first two columns.

I'm aware that you have many types of items. You assert that it's bad to have an extra table for each item type in your system. I don't agree that it's inherently bad. I believe your proposed solution is *far* worse.

You could arrange to give each item a unique id number to allow you to use a single permission table.  See this for an example of how to do that. [Fastest way to generate 11,000,000 unique ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110896/fastest-way-to-generate-11-000-000-unique-ids/20112056#20112056)

Or you could have a single permission table with a type id.

```
   item_to_show  (item id)
   item_type_to_show (item type id)
   order (an integer specifying rule ordering,  needed for this)
   recipient (user id)
   isdenied  (0 means recipient is allowed, 1 means she is denied)
```

In this case the primary key is the first three columns.

Or, you can do what you don't want to do and have a separate permission table for each item type.

Comment: Wow, that's far great explanation, thank you so much @OllieJones... I'm going to use normalized tables from now on. +1 , Best answer

Comment: for the record, I'm going to use the third option `Or you could have a single permission table with a type id.` which contains a compound key of 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

You say, "As I have about 30 data like the 4 data above, I think it will be bad to create one table for every data, and make a many to many relation with the table fs_user"

I agree with the first part of your statement only.  You only need one table.  For the sake of a name, I'll call it ShowableItems.  Fields would be ShowableItemId (PK) and Item.  Some of these items would be email, gender, address, etc.

Then you need a many to many table that shows what items can be shown to whom.  Your three fields would be, the id of the person who owns the item, the showable item id, and the id of the person who can see it.

Comment: Of course I didn't mean a table for every 1 column , No ... I meant that I have other showable data for pages, groups clubs, videos, albums which is different from these data. like for e.g: show_album_to and show_photo_to and show_video_to.

Comment: So, here I'll need to add more tables for : showableAlbumData, showableVideoData, showablePageData, instead of putting them in the tables fs_album, fs_video, fs_photo, and fs_page etc..

Did you get it

Comment: So, As you said before, I'm going to create other tables (for permissions for users, pages, groups etc...) thank you so much my dear, best answer +1

Comment: your answer is very useful too, but OllieJones' is more detailed ... you have both the best answer , thank you all